# Redirect in ExpressJS does not change URL in browser

Tags: express

First off, this is not about a redirect after a POST request via Ajax as I'm aware there're a lot of SO questions regarding this.

What I want is redirecting all requests from `/` to `/app`. However, using the following:

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/app');
});
```

.. it shows the content of the `/app` route without changing the URL in browser. It stays the same `https://example.com/`.

Is there a way to actually redirect with a `302` or `301` http status code?

Comment: Is the request an Ajax call?  Or is it coming direct from the URL bar in the browser?  Ajax calls don't change the browser page at all.  They just report the result to your Javascript.

Comment: @jfriend00 no it's not an Ajax call. With the above route, when I directly visit `/` from the browser. I get the contents of the `/app` route but the URL in the browser bar stays `/`.

Answer (score 2):

**res.redirect** takes two arguments **(code, location)**. code corresponds to  [HTTP status code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) . By default code is taken as **302** which means The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI.

Use **301** code for permanent redirect

```
res.redirect(301, '/app')
```